# How to change color around the next and prev arrows for datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

The datepicker I have contains arrows "prev" and "next". I want to change the color AROUND the arrows (that light pink color) and the arrow style itself:

[image]

I am using downloaded Jquery UI css and I had found out that it contains photos in folder "images" which are used to style "prev" and "next" buttons:

[image: files in image folder]()[![enter image description here]

So I modified all photo links which I have found in jQuery-ui.css file to get blue arrows instead of yellow ones. I modified this line and other similar lines which contained url to photo with yellow arrows in "Image" folder:

```
.ui-icon,
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_228ef1_256x240.png");
}
```

I have also tried to do this code in juery-ui.css file:

```
.ui-datepicker-prev span {
    background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-round-arrow-arrow-head/512/Red_Arrow_Right-512.png) !important;
        background-position: 0px 0px !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-next span {
    background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-round-arrow-arrow-head/512/Red_Arrow_Right-512.png) !important;
        background-position: 0px 0px !important;
}
```

but then my icons just disappeared at all.

I also attempted to change that light pink space around the buttons. I have found its color code: #fef9e2 and searched jQuery-ui.css and other style files for calendar I could find but this color wasn't found at all.

I made a simplified version of attempt to change the arrow buttons:

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });  
  </script>
  
  <style>
 .ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-round-arrow-arrow-head/512/Red_Arrow_Right-512.png");
 }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <input type = "text" id = "datepicker"> 
 </body>
</html>
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I change button icons with link from internet (I dont like color of those in "Image" folder), or download photo for jQuery date picker calendar buttons ?
2. How do I style that light pink space around the buttons?

Comment: Add a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question using the snippet feature.

Comment: Hi, just added a simplified snippet :)

Comment: that's a CSS `border`. Use JavaScript at attach a `mouseover` `mouseout` event listener to all those buttons. That event listener's `this` can be used to attach to sibling or parent elements of your choice whereby you will do `.classList.add('my-border')` and `.classList.remove`...

Comment: You mean like this?? https://jsfiddle.net/z3n27fte/ nothing really happened. Sorry, i dont actually understand your answer. I am not the most experienced programmer yet :)

Comment: Thank you @RonRoyston for your effort, but Mohrn has already answered and it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the size, positioning, and rotation of the arrows. I'm guessing you mean the outline on focus by *that pink color* so I removed that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .ui-datepicker-prev span.ui-icon,
        .ui-datepicker-next span.ui-icon {
            background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-round-arrow-arrow-head/512/Red_Arrow_Right-512.png");
            background-size: contain;
            background-position: center;
        }
        
        .ui-datepicker-prev span.ui-icon {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        
        .ui-datepicker-prev span.ui-icon:focus,
        .ui-datepicker-next span.ui-icon:focus {
            outline: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Amazing! Works just perfectly! Thank you from all my heart! Just what I wanted :)